getting front wheel states with ros2 control Ackerman steering
I have setup a ackerman steering controller with ros2 control. I am using gazebo fortress for the simulation. Everything works except in rviz2, the state of front wheels are not shown and gives the following error:
No transform from [front_left_wheel_link] to [base_link]

Same error is present for front_right_wheel_link as well.
This is what I see in rviz. The front wheels are missing.

The way I understand, the state of these links should be calculated by the gazebo through simulation probably by using information such as friction co-efficients of the wheel. These states in turn must be captured and broadcast-ed by the joint_state_broadcaster so rviz can use them. However I am not sure how to get this to work.
If on the other hand if I run joint_state_publisher_gui, the rviz errors are removed and full state is shown as below. I guess this is because this gui emits information for all these links which rviz can use.

Following is the controller manager configuration:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10  # Hz

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster


    ackermann_steering_controller:
      type: 'ackermann_steering_controller/AckermannSteeringController'


ackermann_steering_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    in_chained_mode: false
    reference_timeout: 2.0
    front_steering: true
    open_loop: false
    velocity_rolling_window_size: 10
    position_feedback: false
    rear_wheels_names: ['rear_right_wheel_joint', 'rear_left_wheel_joint']
    front_wheels_names: ['front_right_steer_joint', 'front_left_steer_joint']
    base_frame_id: base_link
    wheelbase: .6
    front_wheel_track: 2.3
    rear_wheel_track: .3
    front_wheels_radius: 0.1
    rear_wheels_radius: 0.1

The output of ros2 control list_hardware_interfaces is as follows:
command interfaces
        ackermann_steering_controller/angular/position [available] [unclaimed]
        ackermann_steering_controller/linear/velocity [available] [unclaimed]
        front_left_steer_joint/position [available] [claimed]
        front_right_steer_joint/position [available] [claimed]
        rear_left_wheel_joint/velocity [available] [claimed]
        rear_right_wheel_joint/velocity [available] [claimed]
state interfaces
        front_left_steer_joint/position
        front_right_steer_joint/position
        rear_left_wheel_joint/position
        rear_left_wheel_joint/velocity
        rear_right_wheel_joint/position
        rear_right_wheel_joint/velocity

What exactly has to be done in order to get the joint_state_broadcaster to emit required information?

How have you configured the joint_state_broadcaster? Normally, it publishes all joints from gazebo -> have a look at the /joint_states topic, if the missing joint is present there.
robot_state_publisher generates then the TF tree from the joint-states, which is necessary for rviz2. Introspect the tree with view_frames, is there something missing?
Edit, summary from the comments below:
Every joint which is needed to build the TF tree has to be added to the ros2_control tag in the URDF. Otherwise, the robot_state_publisher can't calculate the TF and rviz2 can't show the robot, subsequently.

I have a typical launch setup for the broadcaster as follows: load_joint_state_broadcaster = ExecuteProcess(
cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
'joint_state_broadcaster'],
output='screen'
)

view frame does not have those links. Also please see below the echo of /joint_states topic which does not have this info. header:
stamp:
sec: 63
nanosec: 0
frame_id: ''
name:

rear_left_wheel_joint
rear_right_wheel_joint
front_left_steer_joint
front_right_steer_joint
position:
-3.0624059592494187e-11
-3.0624062481724765e-11
-4.193823411789882e-18
2.9237011418505143e-18
velocity:
-5.047760478818555e-18
-8.047757940281046e-18
.nan
.nan
effort:
.nan
.nan
.nan
.nan


However digram generated using the tool urdf_to_graphviz has all the links.

you showed only the launch file, but there has to be a yaml file where you define the joint_state_broadcaster?

I have edited the question to include the yaml ocntent.

Ok, I see that there no special config for JSB. Can you add the output of ros2 control list_hardware_interfaces?

I edited the question with the output of ros2 control list_hardware_interfaces.

OK, the joints are missing there. You maybe have forgotten to add the joints to the ros2_control tag in the URDF?

Yes adding that fixed it. I was thinking that only the joints that ros2_control actually controls have to be added there. I guess any joint whose state needs monitoring have to be added instead? Thank you for  the support!

Glad that I could help. I updated the summary in my answer, please mark the question as solved.
